# Keep Gridview Headers the same size as column after header freeze

Tags: asp.net, css

So I had to freeze the header bar of a gridview, and I did this using an asp:panel and CSS.

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelContainer" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100%"  ScrollBars="Vertical">

<HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="small" CssClass="HeaderFreeze"  />

.HeaderFreeze
    {
    position:absolute;
    height: 40px;
    top: 80px;

    }
```

My only issue now is that the headers no longer stay the size of the column; is there any way to force the headers to keep the size of the columns (which may change due to the data in them).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic column widths use JavaScript.  Here's a solution using jQuery:

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/z3u8S/) ([fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/z3u8S/show))

Create a duplicate table element with just the header row

```
<table id="panelContainerFixed">
    <tr class="header">
        <th>ID</th><th>Name</th>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="panelContainer">
    <tr class="header">
        <th>ID</th><th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>Name-1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td><td>Name-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td><td>Name-3</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Calculate the widths of the columns and apply those widths to the duplicate header

```
// cache re-usable variables
var $window = $(window),
    $panelContainerFixed = $('#panelContainerFixed'),
    $panelContainer = $('#panelContainer'),
    $header = $('.header'),
    headerPos = $header.offset().top + $header.height();

// set column widths
$panelContainer.find('th').each(function() {
    var $that = $(this);
    $panelContainerFixed.find('th').eq($that.index()).width($that.width());
});
```

Show/Hide the duplicate header based on scrollTop

```
// on window scroll toggle the fixed headers
$window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > headerPos) {
        $panelContainerFixed.show();
    } else {
        $panelContainerFixed.hide();
    }
});​
```